# Wordpress Site footer on Firefox displays a error

Tags: footer

On Firefox I get the following below the footer

`Performance Optimization WordPress Plugins by W3 EDGE

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'Array' was given in /somedirectories/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405`

On Chrome it works fine and the last line on the footer is

`Performance Optimization WordPress Plugins by W3 EDGE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error, it is a warning. You can make this go away by:

- Fixing the warning
- Write errors to the error log instead of the screen ( best practice )

To fix the error, I recommend looking at what's hooking into wp_footer etc, or using a PHP debugger

Comment: I have put /* All errors and warnings to file, instead of html screen */
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
In the wp-config.php, but I still get warnings in the footer, when I use Firefox.

Comment: This is a PHP setting you need to make, the wordpress constants can't always be relied upon, they work on some server configurations but not others

Comment: e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html